# Get the ip of a container to be seen from outside

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine, samba

I am trying to make a shared folder from a container with Ubuntu installing `samba`.

It is a test and I want to do it without creating volumes.

So, how could I see the IP of the container to create the folder in Windows?

I've been doing it with `docker inspect --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' containerId` but the IP that it returns are only for internal networks to docker

Answer (score 0):

1. Run the container by mapping a host port and you should be able to access the container instance with HostIP:HostPort
2. RUN A FTP server in the container and Expose necessary ports, including SSH PORT.
3. Try accessing the files over FTP

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following command?

```
docker container ps
```

Check out the ports attribute, this should give you the output you need.